# Using offsetof with a float in c

Tags: c, offsetof

the code works fine for an int but when I want to use a float it fails unless I cast the structure as a character pointer. Here's what it looks like:

```
struct test
{
    float a;
    float b;
};

void stuff(int offset, test* location);

int main()
{
    test *t;
    t = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));

    char choice = '\0';

    //Find the byte offset of 'a' within the structure
    int offset;
    printf("Edit a or b?");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    switch (toupper(choice))
    {

    case 'A':
        offset = offsetof(test, a);
        stuff(offset, t);
        break;
    case 'B':
        offset = offsetof(test, b);
        stuff(offset, t);
        break;
    }
    printf("%f %f\n", t->a, t->b);
    return 0;
}

void stuff(int offset, test* location)
{
    float imput;
    printf("What would you like to put in it? ");
    scanf("%f", &imput);
    *(float *)((char *)location + offset) = imput;
    //*(float *)(location + offset) = imput   Will Not Work
}
```

`*(float *)(location + offset)= imput` 
Will not work for a float but casting location and the offset as an int pointer will.

I've tried looking online but I couldn't find much about the problem.

Comment: That won't work for ints either.  The reason you need to cast to a `char *` is because of pointer arithmetic.  When you leave the pointer uncasted, it will add `offset * sizeof(test)` to your pointer address which is not what you want.

Comment: The example as given doesn't compile.  Perhaps there is a missing typedef for `test`.  Given that, none of the answers are useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because pointers have 'units', the size of the objects they point to.

Lets assume you have a pointer `p` that points to, say, address 1000.

if you have

```
int* p = 1000;
p += 10;
```

`p` will point to `1040` on 32bit machines, because an `int` has a size of 4 bytes.

But if you have

```
char* p = 1000;
p += 10;
```

`p` will point to `1010`.

That's why

```
*(float *)((char *)location + offset) = imput;
```

works, but

```
*(float *)(location + offset) = imput   Will Not Work
```

doesn't.